# Swiftmailer: Missing interface Swift_CharacterReader

Tags: interface, swiftmailer, implements

I am trying to set up Swiftmailer to send out a personalised newsletter.

I have got most things working (I think): I have the headers and the body all set up, and SMTP authentication working. I get down to `RCPT OK = 250` and `DATA = 354` in the SMTP ‘conversation’, and then of course Swiftmailer starts to go through the body content as it’s supposed to.

But at that point it gets no further; instead, it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Swift_CharacterReader' not found in
/home/swift/lib/classes/Swift/CharacterReader/Utf8Reader.php on line 19
```

Now, `Utf8Reader.php` defines a class `Swift_CharacterReader_Utf8Reader` which implements the interface `Swift_CharacterReader`
—which is defined in `/home/swift/lib/classes/Swift/CharacterReader.php`. But for some reason, it seems that `Utf8Reader.php` is being included and the class attempted instantiated somewhere where `CharacterReader.php` is not (yet) available/included.

So the problem for me now is that SwiftMailer consists of about five bazillion files, and despite quite a bit of searching back and forth, I cannot find out where the call/inclusion might be coming from.

Has anyone else hit their heads against this problem and perhaps know where to look for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is simply a bug in Swiftmailer 4.2.1.

Downloaded version 4.2.0, and it immediately worked. Or at least, it didn’t give me any errors, but gave me this:

```
<< 250 OK id=1Sz8VI-0002Zb-K1 
++ Stopping Swift_SmtpTransport
>> QUIT 
<< 221 cp16.danhost.dk closing connection 
++ Swift_SmtpTransport stopped
```

– which looks like the e-mail was accepted and sent off.

Unfortunately, it’s still not arriving. But that’s a different matter. The interface problem appeared to be just a bug.